# How to only show upper error bar and not lower error bar in a bar graph in python?

Tags: python, bar-chart, errorbar

I want to display only the upper error bar and not the lower error bar
[bar graph here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1Qrk.png)

> ```
> mean.plot.bar()
> plt.title('Liquid Intake')
> plt.ylabel('Intake(ml)')
> x = ['Sucralose','Sucrose','Water']
> plt.errorbar(x, mean, yerr=SEM, ecolor='black', capsize = 3, fmt=' ')
> ```

Thanks!

Comment: try this:[https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barh.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-barh-py](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barh.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-barh-py)

Comment: Sorry, still only shows the error bar in both direction (above and below the tip of the bar). is it possible to get the error bar to only show from the tip of the bar and up. Not showing the bar from the tip of the bar and below?

Comment: BTW, you also have a typo in the title, "Intkae"

Comment: fixed it as a new edit

Answer (score 0):

Just to update, i decided to make the error bar colour the same colour as the bars themselves which camoflouges the lower bar limit. Incase anyone else has this problem, this is one solution...

**EDIT**

nevermind, i include the code zorder=0 to put the errorbar behind the bars

> plt.errorbar(x1, mean, yerr=(SEM),fmt=' ', capsize=(3),zorder=0, ecolor='k')

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).